# how can checksum calculated be different on different hosts which have same code running?

Tags: checksum, message-digest

Is there a way that the checksum calculated using MessageDigest (Java) could be different on 2 hosts? What could be the factors that could lead to this?
I checked the hardware and its same on both hosts.

Comment: The obvious factor is you are hashing two things which are not identical

Comment: The same checksum (or hash) algorithm will always produce the same output for the same input. If it did not do this it would be useless/broken.

Comment: So the two basic possibilities: 1) the input is different; or 2) a different checksum/hash algorithm is used.